# How should I /protect this command for use in \csname?

Tags: macros, expansion

In the process of learning how to use `\csname`, I'm trying to create a macro that allows one to specify integers as arguments and then will yield some content specific to the arguments, like this:

```
\DoContent{1}{3}
```

My current full-example attempt:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}

%End-Content output 
\newcommand{\OneOne}{One One content}
\newcommand{\OneTwo}{One Two content}
\newcommand{\OneThree}{One Three content}
\newcommand{\OneFour}{One Four content}
\newcommand{\OneFive}{One Five content}
\newcommand{\TwoOne}{Two One content}
\newcommand{\TwoTwo}{Two Two content}
% and so on....

%Translator "Switch" statement
\newcommand{\GetNumberText}[1]
{ 
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{One}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{Two}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{Three}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{4}}{Four}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{5}}{Five}{}
}

%csname macro to assemble the content-containing macro
\newcommand{\AssembleNumCmd}[2]{\csname #1#2\endcsname}

%this does not compile: desired functionality
%\newcommand{\DoContent}[2]{\AssembleNumCmd{\GetNumberText{#1}}{\GetNumberText{#2}}}

%this compiles: literal example
\newcommand{\DoContent}[2]{\AssembleNumCmd{One}{Three}}

\begin{document}

\DoContent{1}{3}

\end{document}
```

This should produce

> One Three content

It appears that I can't use any conditional statements inside of the definition of`\GetNumberText` and still pass `\GetNumberText{1}` to `\AssembleNumCmd`. The document doesn't compile if I use the version of `\DoContent` that I have commented there (which is what I want to do).

Obviously, this is some somewhat silly gymnastics, and I'm open to better overall approaches. But, I still need want to know why this relatively simple method isn't working, and what to do to fix it.

I've tried using `\protect` here and there, and using a different "switch" macro that uses `\ifx` instead of `\ifthenelse`, among other smaller changes, and nothing seems to compile without error (" Missing `\endcsname` inserted", and so forth).

Is this a problem with my use of `\csname`? Or am I just being naive about macro expansion and fragility?

Comment: You are trying to use \ifthenelse inside a \csname. This won't work, \ifthenelse is not expandable.

Comment: As a side remark, be careful with all the extra spaces in your `\GetNumberText`. There should be a bunch of `%`'s. Beware that in `LaTeX3` code à la @egreg, `\ExplSyntaxOn` makes spaces in the source completely disappear (they must be input explicitely as `~`). Even with an expandable switch which would work in a `\csname..` you have to be careful with  spaces, as the so-built name may well end up containing such probably unintended spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `expl3` version, storing `One, .... , Ten` in a `\clist` variable:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\OneOne}{One One content}
\newcommand{\OneTwo}{One Two content}
\newcommand{\OneThree}{One Three content}
\newcommand{\OneFour}{One Four content}
\newcommand{\OneFive}{One Five content}
\newcommand{\TwoOne}{Two One content}
\newcommand{\TwoTwo}{Two Two content}
% and so on....

%Translator "Switch" statement



\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_turanc_numbername_clist
\clist_set:Nn \g_turanc_numbername_clist {One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GetNumberText}{m}{%
  \clist_item:Nn \g_turanc_numbername_clist {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff



%csname macro to assemble the content-containing macro
\newcommand{\AssembleNumCmd}[2]{\csname #1#2\endcsname}


\newcommand{\DoContent}[2]{\AssembleNumCmd{\GetNumberText{#1}}{\GetNumberText{#2}}}


\begin{document}

\DoContent{1}{3}

\DoContent{2}{2}

\DoContent{1}{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Old Version**

I replaced the `\ifthenelse` conditional by a 'simpler' `\ifcase ...\or ...\fi` statement for the individual cases. I think it might work with other packages as well.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}

%End-Content output 
\newcommand{\OneOne}{One One content}
\newcommand{\OneTwo}{One Two content}
\newcommand{\OneThree}{One Three content}
\newcommand{\OneFour}{One Four content}
\newcommand{\OneFive}{One Five content}
\newcommand{\TwoOne}{Two One content}
\newcommand{\TwoTwo}{Two Two content}
% and so on....

%Translator "Switch" statement

\newcommand{\GetNumberText}[1]
{%
  \ifcase #1 
  \or
  One%
  \or
  Two%
  \or
  Three%
  \or
  Four%
  \or
  Five%
  \fi
}


%csname macro to assemble the content-containing macro
\newcommand{\AssembleNumCmd}[2]{\csname #1#2\endcsname}

%This does not compile: desired functionality
\newcommand{\DoContent}[2]{\AssembleNumCmd{\GetNumberText{#1}}{\GetNumberText{#2}}}


%this compiles: literal example
%\newcommand{\DoContent}[2]{\AssembleNumCmd{One}{Three}}

\begin{document}

\DoContent{1}{3}


\DoContent{2}{2}

\DoContent{1}{5}


\end{document}
```

**`\ifx` version:

There mustn't be white space characters so be careful when testing etc:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


%End-Content output 
\newcommand{\OneOne}{One One content}
\newcommand{\OneTwo}{One Two content}
\newcommand{\OneThree}{One Three content}
\newcommand{\OneFour}{One Four content}
\newcommand{\OneFive}{One Five content}
\newcommand{\TwoOne}{Two One content}
\newcommand{\TwoTwo}{Two Two content}
% and so on....

%Translator "Switch" statement


\newcommand{\GetNumberText}[1]
{%
  \ifx#11%
  One%
  \else
  \ifx#12%
  Two%
  \else
  \ifx#13%
  Three%
  \else
  \ifx#14%
  Four%
  \else
  \ifx#15%
  Five%
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
}



%csname macro to assemble the content-containing macro
\newcommand{\AssembleNumCmd}[2]{%
\csname #1#2\endcsname%
}

\newcommand{\DoContent}[2]{\AssembleNumCmd{\GetNumberText{#1}}{\GetNumberText{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\DoContent{1}{3}

\DoContent{2}{2}

\DoContent{1}{2}

\DoContent{1}{5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would never use ifcase or long if-else-test for this sort of things. Difficult to extend and debug and maintain.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, it's not nice, but it works ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't even aware of \ifcase. But why does this work and not a set of \ifx statements? I tried the latter and it had the same problem as using \ifthenelse. Wouldn't \ifx be just as primitive as \ifcase?

Comment: @turanc: It should work using `\ifx` but I don't know how you did your code actually

Comment: @turanc: See also my update with the `expl3` version

Comment: I'd use a sequence, that's more efficient, instead of a clist.

Comment: @egreg: `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn` then?

Comment: @turanc regarding `\ifx` it provides expandable tests, but the problem is that you then need a pre-defined macro holding the text to which you want to compare your candidate, one such macro for each possibility. Thus, the simplest is not to have any of this and directly put your `1-1`, `1-2` etc.. in the `\csname` because they are acceptable there and don't need to be translated into `oneone` or whatever. I would recommend though to wrap the input in some space removing helper macros.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, that's the idea

Comment: @egreg: I agree that `seq` ist more efficient, but perhaps efficency isn't an issue here.  (Of course, I can provide a `\seq_` based variant too)

Comment: @turanc: I've added the `\ifx` - version, but it's nasty nesting ;-)

Answer (score 5):

As I already wrote in the comment, using `\ifthenelse` in `\csname` won't work.

Beside this you are overcomplicating things a lot. You already know that command names can contains other things then letters, so then why don't do use this knowledge for the content definitions?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{text1-1}{One One content}
\@namedef{test1-2}{One Two content}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\DoContent}[2]{\csname test#1-#2\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\DoContent{1}{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `\@nameuse{test#1-#2}` then instead of `\csname ... \endcsname`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: tradition ...

Comment: Aha ... well, I improved my solution to be more maintainable and easier to debug ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this response. I didn't know about \@namedef. I marked the next response as answered, though, since it was closer to answering the original question. Gave this an upvote, however.

Comment: `\@namedef`  is only a wrapper for `\expandafter\def\csname ...\endcsname{ ...}` . And I didn't follow your route with the string comparision as I think it is inefficient: it is quite unnecessary to compare the actual string with all lot of other strings all the time only to get its content text.

Answer (score 1):

As Ulrike pointed out, `\ifthenelse` cannot be used in `\csname...\endcsname`, where only macros fully expandable to characters are allowed.

Here's a different implementation using a case switch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DoContent}{mm}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1-#2 }
   {
    {1-1}{One~One~content}
    {1-2}{One~Two~content}
    {1-3}{One~Three~content}
    {1-4}{One~Four~content}
    {1-5}{One~Five~content}
    {2-1}{Two~One~content}
    {2-2}{Two~Two~content}
   }
   {Invalid~choice}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DoContent{1}{3}

\end{document}
```

A possibly better interface for adding cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DoContent}{mm}
 {
  \str_case:nVF { #1-#2 } \g_turanc_choices_tl 
   {Invalid ~ choice}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddContent}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_gput_left:Nn \g_turanc_choices_tl { ##1 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \g_turanc_choices_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\AddContent{
  {1-1}{One One content},
  {1-2}{One Two content},
  {1-3}{One Three content},
  {1-4}{One Four content},
  {1-5}{One Five content},
}

\AddContent{
  {2-1}{Two One content},
}
\AddContent{
  {2-2}{Two Two content},
}

\begin{document}

\DoContent{1}{3}

\DoContent{2}{2}

\DoContent{9}{9}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\AddContent` is cumulative, so pairs can be added even after `\begin{document}`, wherever they become necessary. If you add a pair twice, the one in the last `\AddContent` wins, so you can later override a choice made at startup.

[image]